# Where is var /= "SomeString" documented?

Tags: c++

I have recently seen the following c++ code

```
PathName configFile(pn); 
configFile /= "File.ini";
```

I guess the result is that the File (name) gets appended to the PathName variable. But I have never seen that method described anywhere nor managed to find the appropriate documentation? 
Can someone point me to a valid reference?

Comment: Just a wild guess: the `PathName` class overloads the `/=` operator.

Comment: @Ron That much is obvious; the question is what exactly that class overloaded it to do.

Comment: When asking about a non-standard class, it's often a good idea to mention from where that class comes. (That is, tell us where `PathName` is documented so that someone can find where its behavior is documented.)

Comment: I only realized that it was non-standard when I had finished formulating the question! Am a cpp newbie ... admit I could have guessed the op overloading myself, respectively it rang after the first comment to my Q -> but I was already to lost in  the maze (ie someone elses code) then. @JaMiT thanks for the hint, will do next time ... plus I even got a relevant source in the answer (nice! - SO rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is from [`eckit`](https://github.com/ecmwf/eckit). [Here's the relevant source](https://github.com/ecmwf/eckit/blob/9ded38321cb4dd992b61ef7b997759e3e0b76dc5/src/eckit/filesystem/PathName.cc#L361-L371):

```
PathName& PathName::operator/=(const std::string& s) {
    // TODO: Review me
    *this = PathName(this->asString() + "/" + s);
    return *this;
}

PathName& PathName::operator/=(const char* s) {
    // TODO: Review me
    *this = PathName(this->asString() + "/" + s);
    return *this;
}
```

So given a path to a directory, it changes it to a path to something in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

It is not documented in the C++ reference as the `PathName` is a user-defined type that overloads the [compound assignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_compound_assignment) operator `/=`. It is not a built-in type nor part of the standard-library.

Comment: @Joseph - the moment I saw your comment it made me realize that is overloading! Thanks! Sorry it's already late here ;-)